# Eclipse Plug-in Product DB Connection

Tags: eclipse-plugin

We have an in-house developed Eclipse Plug-in product which is deployed as an exe. It has been running for many years now and the original developer long gone. We do need to migrate the product onto a new server from a desktop. There is no java know-how in the organization.

While I did read about export the plug-in as an executable, I cannot for the life of me figure out where the DB Connection string is defined.

I see references to it as below:

```java
addField(new StringFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.P_CONNECTION_SERVER_NAME, "Server Name:", getFieldEditorParent()));
addField(new StringFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.P_CONNECTION_SERVER_PORT, "Server Port:", getFieldEditorParent()));

String[][] authModes = new String[][]{{"Windows Authentication","0"},{"SQL Server Authentication","1"}};
addField(new RadioGroupFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.P_CONNECTION_AUTH_MODE,
                                    "Server Authentication Mode",
                                    2,
                                    authModes, getFieldEditorParent(), true));
```

However, I cannot dig to th elocation where the server name and port are defined. Looked in "IAApplication.product", build.properties,config.ini,plugin.xml,plugin_customization.ini files, but couldn't locate it.

Any ideas on where this could be defined? In Eclipse preferences or elsewhere?

Any help in this regard will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be using standard Eclipse preferences.

The preferences are stored in the workspace in the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` directory with a file name of `plugin-id.prefs`. This is a Java properties file.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Checked in that directory but no luck. Couldnt locate the server definition.

Comment: That is definitely the location that the code you show uses. If this code has never been run there wouldn't be anything there. The code might also be using a preferences initializer - edit you question and show us the plugin.xml for this plugin.